# What's the colloquial way to express those questions?

Tags: sentence-usage, american-accent

Now, if someone told me that the weather is very bad. I would like to ask about when it started to become bad and for how many days.

Is it okay to use "How long" like:

> How long has it been bad?

Or

> For how long has it been bad?

Also, can I say:

> Since then has it been bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How long has it been bad?

is perfectly fine to ask. A native might say

> How long has it been **that** bad?
>   How long has it been **this** bad?

Your other question

> Since then has it been bad?

is incorrect, and should be

> Since **when** has it been bad?

Comment: So I think "Since then" means "at that time" or "Starting from that time" and it cannot be used as a question word, right?

Comment: Not as a question, but as a *statement*, referring to some earlier time, it's fine to say "Since **then** it's been bad."  .